# On Windows Apache geode server doesn't connect to locator and create region says no members found

Tags: geode

I have an out-of-the-box version of Geode running on Windows. If I start a locator using

```
start locator --name=ibLocator --properties-file="F:\Geode\config\ibGemfire.properties"
```

and then start a server the same:

```
start server --name=ibServer --cache-xml-file="F:\Geode\config\ibCache.xml" --properties-file="F:\Geode\config\ibGemfire.properties" --log-level=info
```

When I connect a GFSH and try `list regions` the `ibCache.xml` doesn't appear to be picked up. I get `no members found`

[image]

When I try `list members` I can only see the locator not the server

[image: members]

If I try and create a region I get `No Members Found`

[image: regions]

This is as if I'm not getting the `bind addresses` correct in the `ibGemfire.properties` file but they look ok to me.

Finally, the SERVER is being created with a locator address `172.22.32.1` instead of an expected `127.0.0.1` address for a local machine.

[image: server]

Answer (score 0):

I basically had to comment out the `locators` config in the `ibGemfire.properties` file like this

[image: locators]

Then when I do `connect` and `list members` and `list regions` I see locator and server and regions as expected

[image: lists]